# How to effectively manage a bunch of jar files and their plumbing?

Tags: java

This is a rather high-level question so apologies if it's off-topic. I'm new to the enterprise Java world.

Suppose I have written some individual Java packages that do things like parse data feeds and store the parsed information to a queue. Another package might read from that queue and ingest those entries into a rules engine package. Tripped alerts get fed into another queue, which is polled by an alerting service (assume it's written in Python) that reads from the queue and issues emails.

As it stands I have to manually run each jar file and stick it in the background. While I could probably daemonize some or all of these services for resiliency or write some kind of service manager to do the same, this strikes me as being very amateur. Especially since I'd have to start a dozen services for this single workflow at boot.

I feel like I'm missing something, but I don't know what I don't know. Short of writing one giant, monolithic application, what should I be looking into to help me manage all these discrete components and be able to (conceptually) deliver a holistic application? I'd like to end up with some sort of hypervisor where I can click one button, it starts/stops all the above services, provides me some visibility into their status and makes sure the services are running when they should.

Is this where frameworks come into play? I see a number of them but don't know if that's just overkill, especially if I'm not actively developing a solution *for* that framework.

Comment: maven is commonly used to manage depedncies, which is kind of what you are asking. But you seem to have a microservice architecture - be happy

Answer (score 1):

It seems you architected a system with a lot of components, and then after some time you decided to aggregate some of them because they happen to share the same programming language: Java. So, first a warning: this is not the best way to wire components together.

Also, it seems you don't know Java very well because you mix terms like package, jar and executable that are totally unrelated and distinct concepts.

However, let's assume that the current state of the art is the best possible and is immutable. Your current requirement is building a graphical interface (I guess HTTP/HTML based) to manage all the distinct components of the system written in Java. I suggest you use a single JVM, writing your components as EJB (essentially a `start()`, `stop()` and a method to query the component state that returns a custom object), and finally wire everything up with the Spring framework, that has a nice annotation-driven configuration for `@Bean`'s.

SpringBoot also has an [*actuator* package](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) that simplify exposing objects. You may also find it useful to register your beans as Managed beans, and using the [Hawtio framework](http://hawt.io/) to administer them (via a Jolokia agent).

Comment: Let's just say the first component was written to be just a faster version of a Python script. The project snowballed from there. At this point I'm trying to tie it all down before it gets any more out of control. Thanks for the lead on Spring, I'm looking into it now

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're writing your application in a [microservice architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices).

You need an orchestrator.

If you are running everything in a single machine, a simple orchestrator that you probably is already running is [systemd](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd). You write systemd service description, and systemd will maintain your services according to your services description. You can specify the order the services should be brought up based on dependencies between services, restart policy if your service goes down unexpectedly, logging for stdout/stderr, etc. Note that this is the same systemd that runs the startup sequence of most modern Linux distros.

If you're running multiple machines, you can still keep using single machine orchestrator like systemd, but usually the requirement for the orchestrator will also become more complex. With multiple machines, you now have to take into account things like moving services between machines, phased roll out, etc. For these setups, there are software that adapts systemd for multi machine orchestration, like CoreOS's [fleetd](https://coreos.com/fleet/); and there are also standalone multi machine orchestrator like [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/). Both uses docker as application container mechanism.

None of what I've described here is Java specific, which means you can use the same orchestration for Java as you used for Python or other languages or architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you're actually using J2EE (i.e. Java Enterprise Edition). It is possible to write enterprise software also in J2SE. J2SE is not having too much available off the shelf for this, but in contrast has a lot of micro-frameworks such as Ninja, or full stack frameworks such as Play framework which work quite well, much easier to program, and performs much better than J2EE.

If you're not using J2EE, then you can go as simple as:

- make one new Java project
- add all the jars as dependency to that project (see the comment on Maven above by NimChimpsky)
- start the classes in the jars by simply calling their constructor

This is quite a naive approach, but can serve you at this point. Of course, if you're aiming for a scalable platform, there is a lot more you need to learn first. For scalability, I suggest the Play! framework as a good start. Alternatively you can use Vert.x which has its own message queue implementation as well as support for high performance distributed caches.

The standard J2EE approach is doable (and considered "de-facto" in many oldschool enterprises) but has fundamental -flaws- or "differences" which makes a very steep learning curve and a very much non-scalable application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose, As Raffaele suggested you can choose to write all your requirements into one app/service. Seems like a possible mission, using java Ejb's or using spring integration - ampqTemplate ( can write to a queue with ampqTemplate and receive the message with a dedicated listener ([example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq)).

Or choosing implementation with microservices architecture. write a service that will push to the queue another one that will contain the listener etc. a task that can be done easily with spring boot.

"One button to control them all" - in the case of a monolithic app - it's easy.
In case that you choose microservices architecture. It depends what are you needs. if its just the "start" "stop" operation I guess that that start and stop of your tomcat/other server will do. For other metrics, there is a variety of solutions. again, it depends on your needs.